# How do I include in-line images when sending with Mailgun API and PHP cURL

Tags: php, mailgun, php-curl

I have been searching SO for clues on how to send in-line images in my emails using the **Mailgun API** and standard **PHP cURL** - *not with the Mailgun SDK* and had no luck, so I've resorted to posting the question.

This is my code so far:

```
$url    = 'https://api:**my-key**@api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/**my-domain.com**/messages';
$from   = 'Admin < admin@my-domain.com >';
$to     = 'Excite User < user@somewhere.com >';

$subject= 'Excite Stuff In Here';
$body   = '<html>
    <img src="cid:logo_sml.png">
    <p>Testing Mailgun API with inline images</p>
</html>';
$text   = strip_tags( nl2br($body) );

$tag    = 'Test';

$inline = ['inline' =>  realpath('../includes/images/logo_sml.png')];

// parameters of message
$params = [
    'from'      => $from,
    'to'        => $to,
    'subject'   => $subject,
    'text'      => $text,
    'html'      => $body,
    'inline'    => json_encode($inline),
    'o:tag'     => $tag
];

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params );

$data_results = curl_exec($curl);

$response = json_decode($data_results);

curl_close($curl);
```

The email is being sent without any error messages but is received with no images - either inline or as an attachment.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I raised a ticket with Mailgun Support and Marco has responded with a solution which I thought I would share:

```
$inline = curl_file_create(realpath('../includes/images/logo_sml.png'));
...
'inline'    => $inline,
```

[curl_file_create](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-file-create.php) — Creates a CURL file object to attach the image.  The rest of the code is unchanged.